# What is the proper way to generate evolutions and models in Play 2?

Tags: playframework-2.1, anorm

I know evolutions are applied automatically in dev mode.  My question is, how do I generate the evolutions? And how do I generate the models that correspond to them?  I'm currently faced with a lot of typing to enter a simple model.  It isn't DRY and there's lots of boilerplate.  This seems counter to the culture of Play.

Here is the code I'm faced with typing, what is the better way?:

1.sql:
    # --- First database schema

```
# --- !Ups

create table task (
  id                        bigint not null primary key,
  title                     varchar(255) not null,
  done                      boolean,
  due_date                  timestamp,
  assigned_to               varchar(255),
  project                   bigint not null,
  folder                    varchar(255),
  foreign key(assigned_to)  references user(email) on delete set null,
  foreign key(project)      references project(id) on delete cascade
);

# --- !Downs

drop table if exists task;
```

Task.scala:

```
package models

import java.util.{Date}

import play.api.db._
import play.api.Play.current

import anorm._
import anorm.SqlParser._

case class Task(id: Pk[Long], folder: String, project: Long, title: String, done: Boolean, dueDate: Option[Date], assignedTo: Option[String])

object Task {

  // -- Parsers

  /**
   * Parse a Task from a ResultSet
   */
  val simple = {
    get[Pk[Long]]("task.id") ~
    get[String]("task.folder") ~
    get[Long]("task.project") ~
    get[String]("task.title") ~
    get[Boolean]("task.done") ~
    get[Option[Date]]("task.due_date") ~
    get[Option[String]]("task.assigned_to") map {
      case id~folder~project~title~done~dueDate~assignedTo => Task(
        id, folder, project, title, done, dueDate, assignedTo
      )
    }
  }

  // -- Queries

  /**
   * Retrieve a Task from the id.
   */
  def findById(id: Long): Option[Task] = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      SQL("select * from task where id = {id}").on(
        'id -> id
      ).as(Task.simple.singleOpt)
    }
  }

  /**
   * Retrieve todo tasks for the user.
   */
  def findTodoInvolving(user: String): Seq[(Task,Project)] = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      SQL(
        """
          select * from task 
          join project_member on project_member.project_id = task.project 
          join project on project.id = project_member.project_id
          where task.done = false and project_member.user_email = {email}
        """
      ).on(
        'email -> user
      ).as(Task.simple ~ Project.simple map {
        case task~project => task -> project
      } *)
    }
  }

  /**
   * Find tasks related to a project
   */
  def findByProject(project: Long): Seq[Task] = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      SQL(
        """
          select * from task 
          where task.project = {project}
        """
      ).on(
        'project -> project
      ).as(Task.simple *)
    }
  }

  /**
   * Delete a task
   */
  def delete(id: Long) {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      SQL("delete from task where id = {id}").on(
        'id -> id
      ).executeUpdate()
    }
  }

  /**
   * Delete all task in a folder.
   */
  def deleteInFolder(projectId: Long, folder: String) {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      SQL("delete from task where project = {project} and folder = {folder}").on(
        'project -> projectId, 'folder -> folder
      ).executeUpdate()
    }
  }

  /**
   * Mark a task as done or not
   */
  def markAsDone(taskId: Long, done: Boolean) {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      SQL("update task set done = {done} where id = {id}").on(
        'id -> taskId,
        'done -> done
      ).executeUpdate()
    }
  }

  /**
   * Rename a folder.
   */
  def renameFolder(projectId: Long, folder: String, newName: String) {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      SQL("update task set folder = {newName} where folder = {name} and project = {project}").on(
        'project -> projectId, 'name -> folder, 'newName -> newName
      ).executeUpdate()
    }
  }

  /**
   * Check if a user is the owner of this task
   */
  def isOwner(task: Long, user: String): Boolean = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      SQL(
        """
          select count(task.id) = 1 from task 
          join project on task.project = project.id 
          join project_member on project_member.project_id = project.id 
          where project_member.user_email = {email} and task.id = {task}
        """
      ).on(
        'task -> task,
        'email -> user
      ).as(scalar[Boolean].single)
    }
  }

  /**
   * Create a Task.
   */
  def create(task: Task): Task = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>

      // Get the task id
      val id: Long = task.id.getOrElse {
        SQL("select next value for task_seq").as(scalar[Long].single)
      }

      SQL(
        """
          insert into task values (
            {id}, {title}, {done}, {dueDate}, {assignedTo}, {project}, {folder}
          )
        """
      ).on(
        'id -> id,
        'folder -> task.folder,
        'project -> task.project,
        'title -> task.title,
        'done -> task.done,
        'dueDate -> task.dueDate,
        'assignedTo -> task.assignedTo
      ).executeUpdate()

      task.copy(id = Id(id))

    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ebean itself doesn't support DDL changes, therefore using automatic evolutions you can only create very first DDL from the scratch.

Next evolutions, you will need to (literally) write yourself, containing all UPs and DOWNs so planning the initial DDL at the beginning is very important step.

**Danger:** As you probably realized yet automatically created 'scratch-evoulution' also performs DOWNs of the previous DDL which means, that all your data is lost.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has two parts - the evolutions and the Scala model. For the evolutions, most DB's have tools to generate most of the SQL code for you (e.g. "forward engineer" in mysql workbench, etc.) and some will generate the diff (alter/update) statements (e.g. mysql workbench's [Synchronize Model](http://mysqlworkbench.org/2013/07/mysql-workbench-troubleshooting-model-synchronization/)) which make creating the evolutions easier.

For the Scala model, you could take a look at the [Cato Crud generator](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1MC5p9SjFIM). I have adapted the templates to my own standards/etc, and they definitely provide a headstart.